# regex match list of words and another word

Tags: regex

I am searching text files that contain:

-any word in this list (build|tune|scrap)
-and one more specific word (engine)

The text files have CRLF as line endings.

I've cobbled together the following regex, which matches when `engine` is on the same line as one of the first three:
`(?=.*\b(build|tune|scrap)\b).*(?=.*\b(engine)\b)`

edit: 
I've tried the suggested duplicate post.  The files I am searching have CRLF line endings, so I believe my regex should have \r\n someplace, but I have been unable to get it to find `engine` in the rest of the text (i.e. on other lines)  when there's a `build`, `tune` or `scrap` anywhere else.
`(?=.*\b(build|tune|scrap)\b)((.|\n|\r)*)(?=.*\b(engine)\b)`
`(?=.*\b(build|tune|scrap)\b)((|\n|\r))(?=.*\b(engine)\b)`

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify a language.

Comment: @liliscent I am using Agent Ransack's Containing Text feature; I am unsure what language that would use.